# Fill all the columns of the dataframe with condition

Tags: python, dataframe, loops, conditional-statements

I am trying to fill the dataframe with certain condition but I can not find the appropriate solution. I have a bit larger dataframe bet let's say that my pandas dataframe looks like this:

| 0 | 1 | 2 | 3 | 4 | 5 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0.32 | 0.40 | 0.60 | 1.20 | 3.40 | 0.00 |
| 0.17 | 0.12 | 0.00 | 1.30 | 2.42 | 0.00 |
| 0.31 | 0.90 | 0.80 | 1.24 | 4.35 | 0.00 |
| 0.39 | 0.00 | 0.90 | 1.50 | 1.40 | 0.00 |

And I want to update the values, so that if 0.00 appears once in a row (*row 2 and 4*) that until the end all the values are 0.00. Something like this:

| 0 | 1 | 2 | 3 | 4 | 5 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0.32 | 0.40 | 0.60 | 1.20 | 3.40 | 0.00 |
| 0.17 | 0.12 | 0.00 | **0.00** | **0.00** | **0.00** |
| 0.31 | 0.90 | 0.80 | 1.24 | 4.35 | 0.00 |
| 0.39 | 0.00 | **0.00** | **0.00** | **0.00** | 0.00 |

I have tried with

```
for t in range (1,T-1):
    data= np.where(df[t-1]==0,0,df[t])
```

and several others ways but I couldn't get what I want.

Thanks!

Comment: Please check [How to make pandas examples](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20109391/how-to-make-good-reproducible-pandas-examples).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try as follows:

- Select from `df` with [`df.eq(0)`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.eq.html). This will get us all zeros and the rest as `NaN` values.
- Now, add [`df.ffill`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.ffill.html) along `axis=1`. This will continue all the zeros through to the end of each row.
- Finally, change the dtype to `bool` by chaining [`df.astype`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.astype.html), thus turning all zeros into `False`, and all `NaN` values into `True`.
- We feed the result to [`df.where`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.where.html). For all `True` values, we'll pick from the `df` itself, for all `False` values, we'll insert `0`.

```
df = df.where(df[df.eq(0)].ffill(axis=1).astype(bool), 0)

print(df)

      0     1    2     3     4    5
0  0.32  0.40  0.6  1.20  3.40  0.0
1  0.17  0.12  0.0  0.00  0.00  0.0
2  0.31  0.90  0.8  1.24  4.35  0.0
3  0.39  0.00  0.0  0.00  0.00  0.0
```